# ion-card horizontal

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular, ionic

Tem alguma forma do ion-card crescer horizontalmente e nao verticalmente?

Ele é preenchido por dados que vem da api

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let filmes of lista_filmes_popular">
        <img [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + filmes.backdrop_path" />
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            {{filmes.original_title}}
          </ion-card-title>
          <p>
            {{filmes.overview}}
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

Tem algum jeito no Ionic dele ir indo horizontalmente e ter um scroll horizontal?

Comment: Já tentou colocar dentro de uma div ou section e habilitar o scroll horizontal nessa div/section? Acho que você pode usar o proprio ion-scroll pra isso também

Comment: eu fiz, mas ele diminui totalmente o tamanho e fica fino a imagem, e nao rola nada

Comment: Vê se isso te ajuda: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-cards-in-a-horizontal-scroll-possible/84746. Se não souber inglês eu coloco a resposta aqui em português

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver com a resposta do @cnotethegr8 na pergunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959258/horizontal-scroll-in-ionic-2